# IIS won't launch?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, iis

I have set up a IIS site on localhost:94, and it runs as it should, I am using visual studio 2012, when I go to launch it this appears...

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to fix it?

It's working fine on the other developers computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running Visual Studio as an Administrator.